# JavaScript: css toggle switch to dark mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I have created a toggle switch using css.

I want `#box1` to turn from a white background with black type to a black with white text and the toggle to turn to ***on***.

I'm stuck trying to figure out the JavaScript. The button doesn't switch and the box doesn't turn back to white.

```
$('#myonoffswitch').change(function(){   
    console.log('here');
    if ($(this).click())
    {
        $('#box1').addClass('dark-mode');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#box1').removeClass('dark-mode');
    }
});
```

How can toggle the `dark-mode` class.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xhtjecw8/3/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the [**toggleClass**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) method. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xhtjecw8/7/)

```
$('#myonoffswitch').change(function(){   
    $('#box1').toggleClass('dark-mode');    
});
```

`$(this).click()` returns an instance of jQuery, which is a truthy value in JavaScript, this is why `addClass` was called in the first place

```js
$('#myonoffswitch').change(function() {
  $('#box1').toggleClass('dark-mode');
});
```

```css
.onoffswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 90px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
  display: block;
  width: 200%;
  margin-left: -100%;
  -moz-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -webkit-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -o-transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before,
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
  content: "ON";
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  content: "OFF";
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  margin: 6px;
  background: #000000;
  border: 2px solid #999999;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 56px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
#box1 {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
#box1.dark-mode {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="onoffswitch">
  <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
    <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
    <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
  </label>
</div>
<br>
<div id="box1">This is text.</div>
```

Comment: Ok, worked in the Fiddle, exactly what I was looking for but did't worked on the site. Even when I just copy yours it dosen't work anymore. http://jsfiddle.net/msashuz4/33/

Comment: You did not include jQuery in this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/msashuz4/33/. Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/msashuz4/34/